# How to override default table style when the table is inside a class?

Tags: css

I have two different style definitions for tables:

```
table {
border: solid 1px #E8EEF4;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Because my specific table is inside a `<div class="checkboxquestion>` i have a special style definition for tables inside this class:

```
.checkboxquestion table
{
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The problem is, that `border: none;` is overriden by `border-collapse: collapse;` - and every other styling option is overriden by the "default" definition.

How do i solve this?

Comment: not sure if it's right here, but could you use !important? Also, can you not give the table a class?

Comment: !important is not working. I can give the table class names, but i would prefer not to if there is another solution

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  `.checkboxquestion table` has a higher specificity than `table`, so its rules shall be obeyed.  And `border` doesn't override `border-collapse` anyway, only `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`.  So your selector must be wrong or something.  Do you have a working example?

Comment: I thought that border: none did not work because i didn't make a definition for TD, so there was a border around everything anyway. My bad.

Comment: ...well, your question says nothing about what you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made another mistake, it works for me the way you did it: Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfGNS/)

Perhaps you didn't close the quotation marks for the div's class as you did in the question?

Answer (score 1):

`div.checkboxquestion table` is also an option ;)

and make sure the specific definition comes after the universal definition.

Answer (score 0):

make a new class and apply it to the table inside of .checkboxquestion

Like:

```
table, .tabelClass {
border: solid 1px #E8EEF4;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

then apply it to your table:

```
<table class="tabelClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go into specificity wars, especially with yourself.
Define all the common table styles by using selectors like table, tr, td, etc.
If you have two different styles of tables, give them two different classes.

If this is a "one time thing", and you really need everything to be the same:

```
.checkboxstyle table {
 border-collapse: separate;
 text-align:center;
 border:none;
}
```

I'm not 100% certain what are you trying to do, but if you're trying to make the border invisible, it would be easier to just color the border in the background color.

```
.checkboxstyle table {
 border-color:blue;
}
```

**You can learn more about specificity** here: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/
And remember, forget everything there as soon as you read it, because you don't want to be calculating specificity. If you find you're doing so, you're writing bad css.